# How to register a click of an anchor tag without navigating to that page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

When the user clicks an anchor tag, I want to store the href attribute associated with that tag and then do stuff with it, but instead of being able to do anything, the browser just goes to that href.

Here's my code:

```
// only if they click anchor tags
$("a").click(function() {

  var source = $(this).href;
  console.log(source);

  // code //

});
```

Why isn't this working? I don't even see anything in the console.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any research before posting this question? It is pretty basic...

Answer (score 4):

Use either `preventDefault();` or `return false;`

Example:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {

    var source = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(source);

    // code //
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

-- OR --

```
$("a").click(function() {

    var source = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(source);

    // code //
    return false;

});
```

---

See also:  http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you want to use `event.preventDefault`.

See the example at http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/